# SQL select statements with multiple tables

Tags: sql

Given the following two tables:

```
Person table 
id (pk) 
first 
middle 
last 
age

Address table 
id(pk) 
person_id (fk person.id) 
street 
city 
state 
zip
```

How do I create an SQL statement that returns all information for people with zip code 97229?

Comment: I'm just not sure where to begin. I understand how to select from a single table, i.e. SELECT * FROM Person WHERE first = "John", but it's the combining of tables where I get lost

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
Select * from people p, address a where  p.id = a.person_id and a.zip='97229';
```

Or you must **TRY** using `JOIN` which is a more efficient and better way to do this as Gordon Linoff in the comments below also says that you need to learn this.

```
SELECT p.*, a.street, a.city FROM persons AS p
JOIN address AS a ON p.id = a.person_id
WHERE a.zip = '97299';
```

Here  `p.*` means it will show all the columns of PERSONS table.

Comment: Your first `where` was incorrect (based on your actual `JOIN` - I have edited it.

Comment: what if there is no relation between both tables, we just want fetch the records one after other

Comment: @SAR thats what I want to do. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @SAR, Adding to my comment above, I dont want to use UNION since that would mean copying the same value (like zip code in the above example) multiple times within the query

Comment: @Anupam,i had long ago the comment, but you mean one from one table and one record from other table while there is not relation between tables or first to fetch all the rows from one table then fetch all the rows from other table!

Comment: I mean looking up the same thing in two tables (example 'person_name') where there is no relation between the tables (i.e no foreign key), and we just want to fetch records one after the other from both tables (assuming same number of columns). We could use UNION but that would mean repeating the expression person_name = 'John' (for example) multiple times in the query. I was looking to avoid that but I guess that isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

You need to join the two tables:

```
select p.id, p.first, p.middle, p.last, p.age,
       a.id as address_id, a.street, a.city, a.state, a.zip
from Person p inner join Address a on p.id = a.person_id
where a.zip = '97229';
```

This will select all of the columns from both tables.  You could of course limit that by choosing different columns in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```
SELECT p.*, a.street, a.city FROM persons AS p
JOIN address AS a ON p.id = a.person_id
WHERE a.zip = '97299'
```

Answer (score 1):

First select all record from person table, then join all these record with another table 'Address'...now u have record of all the persons who have their address in address table...so finally filter your record by zipcode.

```
 select * from Person as P inner join Address as A on 
    P.id = A.person_id Where A.zip='97229'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select P.*,
A.Street,
A.City,
A.State
from Preson P
inner join Address A on P.id=A.Person_id
where A.Zip=97229
Order by A.Street,A.City,A.State
```