# How to join two select queries in one statements and show it to the Datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

My actual question is here and I used the code as suggested.

[I want to sum specific cell values by searching for similar values in textbox in c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407343/i-want-to-sum-specific-cell-values-by-searching-for-similar-values-in-textbox-in)

```
   SELECT s.partnum,partdesc,partmodel,stockin,dateofstockin, (SELECT 
   SUM(stockin)
   FROM Tbl_SpareParts
   GROUP BY partnum
   HAVING partnum = s.partnum) AS FinalTotalStockIN FROM Tbl_SpareParts s

   SELECT s.partnum,partdesc,partmodel,outstock,outstockdate,outstockcaseid_billnum,remarks, (SELECT SUM(outstock)
   FROM Tbl_OutCaseID
   GROUP BY partnum
   HAVING partnum = s.partnum) AS FinalTotalStockOut FROM Tbl_OutCaseID s
```

How to join above two select statements?

I tried with INNER JOIN but I also want the sum of above stockin and stock out by using first above sum statements.

```
 SELECT Tbl_SpareParts.partnum, Tbl_SpareParts.partdesc, 
 Tbl_SpareParts.partmodel, Tbl_SpareParts.stockin, 
 Tbl_SpareParts.dateofstockin, Tbl_OutCaseID.partnum AS Stockoutpartnum, 
 Tbl_OutCaseID.partdesc AS Stockoutpartdesc, 
 Tbl_OutCaseID.partmodel AS stockoutpartmodel, Tbl_OutCaseID.outstock, 
 Tbl_OutCaseID.outstockdate, Tbl_OutCaseID.outstockcaseid_billnum, 
 Tbl_OutCaseID.remarks
 FROM Tbl_SpareParts INNER JOIN
 Tbl_OutCaseID ON Tbl_SpareParts.SN = Tbl_OutCaseID.SN
```

Comment: Tried with join before? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901614/sql-select-statements-with-multiple-tables

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what DBMS you are using, but a lot of mainstream DBMS support both windowing functions and the `with` clause that lets you define and cascade subqueries.  Even if your DBMS does not support these, you could rewrite the query a little bit to make it work.

If I understand your question correctly, I think something like this might accomplish what you are seeking:

```
with spare_parts as (
 SELECT
   s.partnum,partdesc,partmodel,stockin,dateofstockin,sn,
   sum (stockin) over (partition by partnum) as stockin_total
 FROM Tbl_SpareParts s
),
cases as (
 SELECT
   s.partnum,partdesc,partmodel,outstock,outstockdate,outstockcaseid_billnum,remarks,
   sn, SUM(outstock) over (partition by partnum) as outstock_total
 FROM Tbl_OutCaseID
)
select
  s.partnum, s.partdesc, s.partmodel, s.stockin, 
  s.dateofstockin, s.stockin_total,
  c.partnum AS Stockoutpartnum, 
  c.partdesc AS Stockoutpartdesc, 
  c.partmodel AS stockoutpartmodel, c.outstock, 
  c.outstockdate, c.outstockcaseid_billnum, 
  c.remarks, c.outstock_total
from
  spare_parts s
  join cases c on s.sn = c.sn
```

Another possibility is you wanted the sum of stock-ins and stock-outs for each part on a single line, but I wasn't sure.  If that's the case, then the above is wrong, but you could achieve it by changing the windowing functions to normal aggregate (`GROUP BY`) within each of the subqueries.

Comment: This works but, It`s not showing full datas. If there are 6 rows in "Tbl_stockin" and 4 rows in "Tbl_Stockout". It`ll only show 4 rows because sn=sn. Itried it with group by but didn`t worked.

Comment: Also, rows will repeat